# Executar função ao fechar modal no Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

Estou utilizando Bootstrap 4 em um projeto com Vue;

No modal, tenho um vídeo em um iframe do Youtube;

O que preciso fazer, é pausar este vídeo, quando fecho o modal, seja apertando a tecla <kbd>esc</kbd>, ou fechando no `x` do modal ou clicando fora do modal para fechá-lo.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de função que posso efetuar para pausar este vídeo?

Obs: não estou usando jQuery.

edit: Este modal está dentro de um componente Vue, por isso acredito que jQuery não vai funcionar.

Segue código:

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal Vídeo-->
          <div class="modal fade" id="ModalVideo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalVideoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content content_modal">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div class="corpo_video">
                  <iframe width="100%" height="450px"
                    :src="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+texto[0].video">
                  </iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Botão:

```
<div class="company__box pop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalVideo">
 <span>
  Assista ao nosso
   vídeo institucional
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Não seria só adicionar uma função de click no button de fechar?Tipo `@click="minhaFuncaoPause()"`

Comment: Utilize a [API do YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br), caso contrário você não conseguirá controlar o player dentro de um iframe.

Comment: Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3s1jwx5g/

Comment: Não entendi como vc está usando BS4 sem jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue parar o vídeo via JavaScript usando o método **[.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**. Para isso adicione o parâmetro `?enablejsapi=1` no `src` do vídeo:

```
:src="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+texto[0].video+'?enablejsapi=1'"
```

Crie uma função que será chamada quando a modal for fechada pelo evento `hide.bs.modal`. A função conterá o método que irá fazer o vídeo pausar:

```
function paraVideo(){
   document.querySelector('.modal-body iframe')
   .contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
}
```

> O valor em `func` `pauseVideo` faz o vídeo *pausar*. Se quiser fazer o
>   vídeo *parar* troque por `stopVideo`.

Você chama a função pelo evento quando a modal fechar:

```
$('#ModalVideo').on('hide.bs.modal', paraVideo);
```

**[Veja no JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/st7z43no/)**

Comment: Opa, sabe me informar pq essa função não está rodando aqui?